# What's the best practice for including a .env file in a jenkins build?

Tags: django, jenkins, docker, environment-variables, 12factor

Here is my situation:
I have a Django app, which depends on config values being stored in a `.env` file. This `.env` file is separate from source control, to keep sensitive info private. This Django app is deployed in a docker container, and I have jenkins set up to rebuild the container whenever changes are checked into our git repository. The build will fail unless there is a `.env` file present in the build environment. What is the best way to include that file?

I currently have jenkins set up to execute a shell command that writes the file to the build environment, but I can't help but feel like that is sub-optimal, security-wise. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: When you say the shell command writes the file to the build environment you mean that it does an echo to a file or similar? If so, a better way of doing it would be having the env file locally stored in the host machine (with secure permissions) and then use the shell command to copy the file from the host to the container using cp/scp/rsync

Answer (score 2):

The answer we have come up with is to store the file on s3, and use aws cli to fetch the file at build time. Since the build is destined to be uploaded to ec2 anyway, it makes sense to use the aws credentials for both operations.

Answer (score 0):

Would including the file to source code with access granted only to you/authorised users break your privacy policy?
Else you can try to always keep the file in Jenkins workspace dir and never delete it when cleaning workspace.